Is there a way to set a custom keyboard layout for Ubuntu Frame
I'm building a kiosk based on Ubuntu Frame that will need to startup a Firefox browser, however I also need to disable the ctrl keys so I created a keyboard layout that seems to work fine outside of Ubuntu Frame but not within it. I've tried setting the keyboard using gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'tss_kiosk')]" but that didn't seem to work.
I expect a browser to start up with the ctrl keys not functional

Please edit to include the [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you're having.  We can't help you debug code we cannot see.

The minimal reproducible example is to install ubuntu-frame with the firefox browser opening a page with the --kiosk mode and hit the ctrl+t key. The ctrl key should not open up a new tab. The ctrl+w should not allow you to close the browser.

If you're programming, you must at least have a program that you're writing.  Or perhaps you posted to the wrong place?   See Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on? for guidance.
